# In MAC Chrome, table is not read completely using voiceover

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

When VoiceOver is enabled on Mac Chrome, only the visible part of a table is read out, and the remaining part that is not visible on the screen is not read.

This problem is specific to Chrome on Mac, and other browsers are capable of reading the entire table.

Comment: Codepens to reproduce issue are :  
[link-1](https://codepen.io/sivachaitanyaa-backflipt-com/pen/RwervMr)
[link-2](https://codepen.io/sivachaitanyaa-backflipt-com/pen/dyqxEBw)

Comment: And what's your question? Do you want confirmation that it's a chrome bug? Are you checking if you can work around it? When you say it only reads the visible part, are you using the "read all" command or are you navigating cell by cell? Perhaps try some of the navigation mentioned here - https://support.apple.com/guide/voiceover/navigate-webpage-tables-vo27958/mac

Comment: I am not sure if is a Chrome bug but I can see this issue as of now only on mac chrome.
I am navigating cell by cell in the table using vo+arrow key. 
Chrome version I am using is 112.0.5615.49 and MAC version is 13.2.1 (22D68)

Comment: I have been having this same issue. Have you found anymore information or how to work around it?